# Use RegEx or "import time" to capture a date

Tags: python

I'm using Python and would like to parse the date out of hundreds of emails, in addition to other stuff. The date always comes in the form:

```
Sent: Tuesday, January 19, 2016 9:52 AM
```

Initially I only needed the year, so for my RegEx I was using `(r'Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b')` but now I need the entire date.

Is it wisest to use a very long RegEx capturing all 12 possible months and all 31 possible days, or using the `import time` and `time.strptime("December 31, 2012", "%B, %d, %Y")` method which I just stumbled upon online? I don't really understand how the latter method works so I'm hesitant to use it...

For parsing the table I'm using BeautifulSoup. For parsing just the year I've been using this block of code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path): #capture email year
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b')
            email = f.read()
            dates = pattern.findall(email)
            if dates:
                export_year = (''.join(dates))
                print("export_year:", export_year)
```

Here's an example of what one of the emails looks like:

[image]

And the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: Corrected  NEFS 2 Available Qutoa 1/19</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: Corrected  NEFS 2 Available Qutoa 1/19</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>1/19/2016 3:22 PM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma",sans-serif;}
p.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, div.msonormal0
    {mso-style-name:msonormal;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";
    font-family:"Tahoma",sans-serif;}
span.EmailStyle20
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
span.title1
    {mso-style-name:title1;
    font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
    color:#1F487E;
    font-weight:normal;}
span.EmailStyle22
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none none;}
span.EmailStyle23
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle24
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle25
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">Please see below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><i><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Demi&quot;,sans-serif;color:#002776">Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#DE3500">~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style="color:#DE3500"><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<div>
<div style="border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>From:</b> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br>
<b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, January 19, 2016 9:52 AM<br>
<b>To:</b> David Leveille &lt;nefs02@gmail.com&gt;<br>
<b>Subject:</b> Corrected NEFS 2 Available Qutoa 1/19<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F487E">AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2015</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="75%" style="width:75.76%">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:35.25pt">
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:35.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><b><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">ID
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:35.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt"><b><span style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Available Quota
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:35.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt"><b><span style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Live Weight Pounds
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:35.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt"><b><span style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Price
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:35.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt"><b><span style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Date Posted
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">004<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Greysole<br>
GBE COD<br>
GOM COD<br>
SNE BB<br>
SNE YellowTail<br>
GOM YellowTail<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">2,640<br>
308<br>
576<br>
727<br>
232<br>
447<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$1.30</span><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$0.55</span><span style="color:#1F497D"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$2.75<br>
$0.10<br>
$0.20<br>
$0.40<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/19<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">370<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Greysole<br>
Dabs<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">2,000<br>
1,000<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Trade for 7,000 GOM YellowTail<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/13<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1734<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">gom hadd<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">3,987<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$0.45<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/12<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1484<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Greysole
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">3,000<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$1.30<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/12<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1484<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Dabs<br>
Greysole<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1,000<br>
2,000<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Trade for 2,000 GOM COD<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/6<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1878<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">GOM COD<br>
Whake<br>
Greysole<br>
Dabs<br>
GB YT<br>
SNE YT<br>
GB BB<br>
GOM BB<br>
SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">713<br>
23,515<br>
2,745<br>
3,715<br>
651<br>
265<br>
3,762<br>
4,321<br>
4,188<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$4.75<br>
$0.04<br>
$2.00<br>
$1.80<br>
$0.70<br>
$0.30<br>
$0.04<br>
$0.03<br>
$0.15<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/6<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">512<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Dabs<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">2,000<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Trade for 2,000 GOM COD<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">12/31<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1818<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Dabs<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">2000<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Trade for 6,000 of GOM Yellow Tail<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1/6<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">293<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Pollock<br>
SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">67,283<br>
2,270<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$0.02<br>
$0.10<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">10/20<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">1830<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="190" style="width:142.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="141" style="width:105.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">3,606<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="133" style="width:99.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">$0.05<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">7/13<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:69.0pt">
<td width="156" style="width:117.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:69.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:15.0pt"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">347<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td
```

Comment: Do you need to read the date from within a wider body of text, or is it available as its own variable?

Comment: The second one. Just increase your level of understanding and you'll be good to go! ;)

Comment: @asongtoruin I added a picture of what one of the emails looks like. So I think to answer you, it is within a body of other text

Comment: @CharlesMorris so I know this is probably another dumb question but how do I actually get a printout of/export the date with the second method? Do I simply do `print(time.strptime)` ?

Comment: How are you parsing the emails? Are they in text file format?

Comment: @theprowler Well, you need to provide the strings that you were unable to convert to datetime. Provide input(file/string) and expected output(file/string) along with code that you tried.

Comment: @asongtoruin the emails are all HTML Firefox files that I've been using BeautifulSoup and RegEx to parse

Comment: @MYGz the date string that I can't capture is always in the `Sent:` line. And I just added the code I've been using

Comment: Does the line containing the date only contain, for example, `Sent: Tuesday, January 19, 2016 9:52 AM`? Or is there other text/tags around it?

Comment: @theprowler What you can do is capture everything after `Sent:(.*)$` and then pass the captured string into `dateutil.parser.parse()` method. If you can remove the image and include the input as html as text, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: @asongtoruin Yes, as you can see in the screenshot above that is all that will ever be there.

Comment: `strptime` isn't a Pythonism -- it's actually a C library call, with a very long history and very wide availability; you'll find it in many, many languages. As such, it's worth getting used to, since it's a nearly-ubiquitous tool.

Comment: @MYGz Ok I've never used that `dateutil.parser.parse()` method but I can give it a try. When you say capture everything after `Sent:` though do you mean with RegEx?

Comment: @theprowler Yep with regex.

Comment: I added the HTML code btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `html = """your_html"""` you can try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import parser
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a = re.findall(r'Sent:(.*)',soup.text)[0]
d = parser.parse(a)
print d
print d.timetuple()
```

Output:

```
2016-01-19 09:52:00
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=9, tm_min=52, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=19, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: this is a much better approach if the user is already using BS to parse the email

Comment: Quick (and simple) question: how do I print the year, month, and day separately from that `timetuple()` variable? Doing `print(d.timetuple(tm_year))` didn't work for printing just the year

Comment: @theprowler `d` is a python datetime object, you can get it with `d.year`, `d.month`, `d.day`. I just printed the timetuple to show the different parts.

Comment: So I ran the code on another email and it's now saying that the line `d = parser.parse(a)` produces the error `ValueError: Unknown string format`. When I `print(a)` though, the date is still within `a` so what could be causing this error?

Comment: Do you mean `a`? Here is `a` = `Friday, June 14, 2013 12:07 PMTo: David LeveilleSubject: NEFS 2 Available Quota 6/14 AVAILABLE QUOTA 2013 ID Available Quota Live Weight Pounds Price Date Posted 310GB Cod West  GOM Cod  GOM Haddock  CC/GOM Yellowtail Flounder  Plaice  Witch Flounder  GOM Winter Flounder  Redfish  White Hake  Pollock SNE/MA Winter Flounder 9552076647868127651572873472796363212Package $8,0006/141610SNE Winter FlounderSNE YellowTail2,627932Package $1,9506/4004GBE`

Comment: We need to match only `Friday, June 14, 2013`. We will have to adjust the regex.

Comment: Ok.... but just so I know, what exactly is failing? I thought the current code works this way: 1) RegEx captures everything after `Sent:` 2) we use the `dateutil` and `parser` to capture a date from within everything after `Sent:`. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @theprowler It will work fine if `Sent: date` is on separate line, because `.*` will match everything till a newline character. The regex is failing here, because after `Friday, June 14, 2013 12:07` there is no `'\n'` character.

Comment: Ohhhhh gotcha. So in order to solve this, we'll either have to use RegEx to capture just the date, or capture only a certain number of characters after `Sent:`, or capture everything up until that first `<br>` in the HTML code

Comment: @theprowler You need to match only the date string after `Sent:`. Adjust the regex as such that it doesn't captures anything after date string.

Comment: Is there a way to end the RegEx at `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by MYGz in the comments, we can use `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse the text-date, like so:

```
from dateutil import parser
import re

email_data = '''
...
<div style="border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>From:</b> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br>
<b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, January 19, 2016 9:52 AM<br>
<b>To:</b> David Leveille &lt;nefs02@gmail.com&gt;<br>
<b>Subject:</b> Corrected NEFS 2 Available Qutoa 1/19<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
...
'''

date_pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:</b>\s+(.*)<br>')

find_date = re.findall(date_pattern, email_data)

time_obj = parser.parse(find_date[0])

print int(time_obj.year)
print int(time_obj.month)
print int(time_obj.day)
```

The `.year` etc lines are examples of the properties that `time_obj` will have as it is unclear what further date information you are seeking from this piece of text. This will print:

```
2016
1
19
```